# Display table information based on a file read in

Tags: lua

So I was able to put data from a file into a table and set the first word of each line a key. How do I display whats in the table in an order based on reading in another file with just the keys?

```
-- see if the file exists
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open("data.txt", "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

-- get all lines from a file, returns an empty
-- list/table if the file does not exist
function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines("data.txt") do
    first_word = string.gmatch(line, "%a+") -- word
    lines[first_word] = line
  end
  return lines
end

local lines = lines_from(file)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code:

```
-- see if the file exists
function file_exists(file)
    local f = io.open(file, "rb") -- <-- changed "data.txt" to file
    if f then f:close() end
    return f ~= nil
end

-- get all lines from a file, returns an empty
-- list/table if the file does not exist
function lines_from(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
    lines = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do -- <-- changed "data.txt" to file
      first_word = string.match(line, "%a+") -- <-- changed gmatch to match (IMPORTANT)
      lines[first_word] = line
    end
    return lines
end

local lines = lines_from(file)
```

I removed the last end since it didn't match any block.
The change gmatch to match is critical, since gmatch returns an iterator, a *function*.

Regarding your question: read the key file, but save its entries in an array manner:

```
function key_file(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
    keys = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
      key = string.match(line, "%a+")
      table.insert(keys, key)
    end
    return keys
end
```

In another place you iterate over the key array, using the keys for the lines table:

```
local lines = lines_from("data.txt")
local keys = key_file("keys.txt")

for i, key in ipairs(keys) do
    print(string.format("%d: %s", i, lines[key]))
end
```

Comment: Do I need to keep where you said file as data.txt? When i make it file its giving me errors

Comment: how do i add line 1 in front of the first out put and so on?

Comment: @CorDell: Since you are using functions i assumed you were calling them in a manner like this: `lines_from("data.txt")` (as you can see in my last code example) 
Lua won't complain if you don't do this but then it will receive a nil value for the filename and that won't work.
So you have to pass the filename to lua. In your example, the first filename is "data.txt", for the keyfile i just took "keys.txt". But you surely have to adopt this to your case.

For your second comment: use print together with string.format. I edited my answer to accomplish this.